# HTML file Tries to Find HTML File in Wrong Location

Tags: html

Somehow my HTML file is trying to locate another separate HTML file in the wrong folder location even when I set the iframe source to the correct location!

I was reorganizing all my files into a new folder but the two files are all in the same folder. I doublechecked that the source file name was correct and the location was correct and I was viewing the correct files and everything, but it still attempted to find a file name that didn't exist in the wrong folder (It previously worked before the reorganization).

I tried everything and the page said: Firefox can't find the file at /E:/Art/Animation & Computing/Website/Programming Files/Backup Files/Drawing-Content.html. 
The correct location and file name is: E:\Art\Animation & Computing\Website\Programming Files\Literature.html.

Here is the first file that calls the other file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div>
              <h1>Literature</h1>
              <iframe src="Literature.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="1000px" height="7000px">
              </iframe>
            </div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the second file that is being called:

```
<p>Here is all the literature content and it should be displayed after the Literature header</p>

<img src="whole-pic-copy.jpg">
```

Just saying, the entire reason I'm implementing a separate HTML file into an HTML file is because I have long lists of code (this is just a part of the code) and I want to organize it so it is easy to manage. And also, this method worked perfectly before and now it isn't so I just want to focus on trying to debug this. Do I have to clear the history or something, because it seems to remember the past location and name of the file.

Comment: @Zange-chan if you can notice this man is using file location to see html, which means that he doesn't have a web server installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the file which is missing is `Drawing-Content.html` but what I suppose since you renamed it to `Literature.html` the first page (the page that is calling) is cached. So you need to clear the cache in your browser, make sure you saved your files correctly and then reload that page :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jquery as well:

```
<div id="literature"></div>

<script>
  $(function () {
      $("#literature).load("includes/literature.html");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I need to download the jQuery library?  Sorry, I'm new to jQuery. Where can I get it, if I need to?

Comment: hi, yes you would need the jQuery library. I recommend to fetch it from the CDN: https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Here's more info on getting scripts from the CDN: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/